# Set a drop-down value from GET variable laravel 5.2

Tags: forms, select, get, laravel-5

I built following select form element in my laravel project:

```
{!! Form::select('chapter', [1=>'First', 2=>'Second', 3=>'Third'], [2], ['multiple']); !!}
```

It works fine, till I add `chapter` to the URL as GET variable.
On the page like `project.dev/page?chapter[]=2` the same form does not have selected option.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

The problem was in the vendor's code :(

`\Collective\Html\FormBuilder line 719 in the method getSelectedValue($value, $selected):`

```
return in_array($value, $selected, true) ? 'selected' : null;
```

But in the previous (5.1) and the next (5.3) versions this line looks like following:

```
return in_array($value, $selected, true) || in_array((string) $value, $selected, true) ? 'selected' : null;
```

In that edition everything works as expected.
Additionally you can compare source code:
https://github.com/LaravelCollective/html/blob/5.3/src/FormBuilder.php and 
https://github.com/LaravelCollective/html/blob/5.2/src/FormBuilder.php